# If the last dropdown option is selected then show input box

Tags: jquery

If the last option in a select menu is selected I would like to show the otherBox. I do not want to do this based on value as the value will change, instead I would like to select the last option in the select menu.
This is what I tried:

```js
jQuery('select#dropdown').change(function () {
if ($('select#dropdown option:last').attr("selected", "selected")) {
 $('#otherBox').show();
} else {
$('#otherBox').hide(); 
}
});
```

```css
#otherBox {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test2</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>

<div id="otherBox">
test
</div>
```

Comment: Note that many ***properties*** like selected don't get reflected in the ***attributes*** when changed by user. Also your `if()` is actually *setting* the attribute. Another good example is `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses toggle to hide/show based on if the last option is selected.

**find** searches the children
**is** returns boolean and **:selected** determines if the option is selected or not

For **attr**, when passing two values you are actually setting the attr(first value) to the second value. So your if statement isn't actually checking it instead it is always setting the last option as selected.

```js
jQuery('select#dropdown').change(function () {
$('#otherBox').toggle($(this).find("option:last").is(":selected")); 
});
```

```css
#otherBox {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test2</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>

<div id="otherBox">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

may be this will help you.

```js
jQuery('select#dropdown').change(function () {
var checkOther = $('select#dropdown').val();
if ( checkOther == 'other' ) {
 $('#otherBox').show();
} else {
$('#otherBox').hide(); 
}
});
```

```css
#otherBox {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option value='Test'>Test</option>
<option value='Test2'>Test2</option>
<option value='other'>Other</option>
</select>

<div id="otherBox">
test
</div>
```

Comment: The original question stated not based on value.

Comment: I think it was not your concern. and without value is it just showcase. Avoid like this behavior.